# MySQL get unique key while selecting

Tags: mysql, uniqueidentifier

I'm making this select:

```
select code,name from talbe1
union all
select code,name from table2
```

The actual code isnt important to me but what is important to me is that the code column will be unique column, and with this select I cant grantee it..
Is there any save word/something that will give me something like that:

```
select getUniqueCode(),name from(
select name from talbe1
union all
select name from table2)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [mysql UUID call](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). Which would result in something like this:

```
select UUID(),name from(
select name from talbe1
union all
select name from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove "all":

```
select code,name from table1
union
select code,name from table2
```

`Union all` keeps al rows.
`Union` removes duplicates.

If you have different names for the same code in each table, you have to pick one name - try this:

```
select code, max(name) as name
from (select code,name from table1
    union
    select code,name from table2) x
group by 1
```